# Is there a way to test code that makes API calls without mocking?

Tags: react-native, automated-tests

I have a FlatList that implements endless scrolling. First it fetches data from a third-party API (Marvel). Then when user scrolls to the end it fetches more. I'm having issues with a duplicate ID in the Flatlist so want to add tests to check for this. However, Jest forces you to mock API calls. Is there a way to do the test without mocking?

I'm trying to avoid an E2E test framework if possible or is that the only way?

EDIT: Code below if it's relevant:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {CText} from '@components/CText';
import {fetchComics} from '@apis/marvelApi';
import {useState} from 'react';
import {Comic, ComicsResponse} from '@src/types/marvel';
import {CActivityIndicator} from '@components/CActivityIndicator';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {ActivityIndicatorType} from '@src/types';
import styles from './styles';

const renderItem = ({item, index}: {item: Comic; index: number}) => {
  return <CText type="paragraph">{item.title}</CText>;
};

const keyExtractor = (item: Comic) => {
  return item.id.toString();
};

/**
 * https://developer.marvel.com/docs#!/public/getComicsCharacterCollection_get_2
 * Will get 409 error if Limit greater than 100
 */
const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 100;

interface Props {
  characterId: number;
}

const initialState = {
  offset: 0,
  totalResults: -1,
};

/**
 * For some reason this component doesn't unmount if you leave the screen
 * by pressing the back button
 */
const ComicsComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const [comics, setComics] = useState<Comic[]>(undefined);
  const [isBusy, setIsBusy] = useState(true);
  const [activityIndicatortype, setActivityIndicatorType] = useState<
    ActivityIndicatorType
  >('absolute');

  const state = useRef(initialState);
  const characterId = props.characterId;

  /**
   * This effect gets called on load and should always have offset 0
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    state.current = initialState;
    setActivityIndicatorType('absolute');
    setIsBusy(true);
    setComics(undefined);
    const offset = 0;

    fetchComics(characterId, offset, ITEMS_PER_PAGE).then(
      (response: ComicsResponse) => {
        setIsBusy(false);
        setComics(response.data.results);
        setActivityIndicatorType('small');
        state.current.totalResults = response.data.total;
      },
    );

    return () => {
      console.log('Component unmounted');
    };
  }, [props.characterId]);

  /**
   * This function gets called when the user scrolls to end of FlatList
   */
  const endReachedHandler = () => {
    if (
      state.current.totalResults > 0 &&
      state.current.offset < state.current.totalResults
    ) {
      if (isBusy) {
        return;
      }
      const newOffset = state.current.offset + ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
      state.current.offset = newOffset;
      setIsBusy(true);
      fetchComics(characterId, newOffset, ITEMS_PER_PAGE).then(
        (response: ComicsResponse) => {
        
          setIsBusy(false);
          if (newOffset > response.data.total) {
            return;
          }
          //do nothing since we reached the end
          else {
            console.log(`Offset: ${newOffset} Comics length:${comics.length}`);

            const newComics = [...comics, ...response.data.results];
            setComics(newComics);
          }
        },
      );
    }
  };

  const content = () => {
    if (comics) {
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={comics}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          onEndReachedThreshold={2}
          onEndReached={endReachedHandler}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.flex}>
      {content()}

      {isBusy && <CActivityIndicator type={activityIndicatortype} />}
    </View>
  );
};

export {ComicsComponent};
```

Comment: Share your code so can guide you accordingly. Have you used keyExtractor in flat list?

Comment: Yes. Just updated post to include code. Not sure if it's useful because it's possible the API is doing something weird but sending the wrong stuff randomly.

It's also hard for me to check in postman because I need to make several requests in a row (with increasing offset) for the bug to appear. I have found Postman good for just singular requests.

Comment: Postman is good for response testing. You can console.log(request) data and check on Postman requesting and response over there one request at a time with params.

Comment: If id's are duplicating then you can change your keyExtract code like "const keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
  return index.toString();
};"

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can do API calls in Jest tests in react-native by using axios package.

```
import 'react-native';

import axios from 'axios';

const TIMEOUT = 5000;

beforeEach(() => {});

it(
  'can call Axios',
  async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('https://api.scryfall.com/sets');
    expect(result.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(result.data.object).toEqual('list');
  },
  TIMEOUT,
);
```

I had troubles doing this with the plain fetch package.